# Plotting multiple variables in time series with greyscale and shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a time-series graph with multiple y values. I would like to change the shape of the different variables so some are solid, some are dashed etc. I would also like all the colors to be on greyscale.
Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

I know how to melt my data so that I can plot them all together by the value of the variables but right now I cannot get the shapes to change or the greyscale. Thank you in advance.

`ggplot(melted_data, aes(x = Distance, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_line()`

```
data <- structure(list(Distance = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                                12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
                                28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
                                44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
                                60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
                                76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
                                92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
                                27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
                                43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 
                                59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 
                                75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 
                                91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
                                10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
                                26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
                                42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
                                58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 
                                74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 
                                90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
                                8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
                                24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 
                                40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
                                56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 
                                72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 
                                88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99), variable = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                        1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Mg", 
                                                                                                                                                                "Mn", "Zn", "Ba"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.903247645, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.912560748, 0.896003508, 0.909572697, 0.883631829, 0.905722594, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.892465355, 0.909271173, 0.880506202, 0.889278401, 0.878534542, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.959209459, 0.913303825, 0.929893977, 0.97778374, 0.9885554, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.929716333, 1.028422583, 1.025638955, 1.011352651, 1.041343955, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.092562951, 1.129761801, 1.088857171, 1.107257284, 1.116728405, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.103053734, 1.041662037, 1.134182243, 1.104550315, 1.086952767, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.106004784, 1.057688595, 1.034347579, 1.04641385, 1.139270945, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.048446018, 1.033827731, 1.075554754, 1.029893202, 1.074749532, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.001626205, 0.977053541, 0.987467665, 0.999540478, 0.945184816, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.959677178, 0.962807712, 0.967023936, 1.024286493, 0.881264816, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.967181342, 1.000316876, 0.956168258, 1.003214572, 1.00047837, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.940103474, 0.929875987, 0.928227112, 0.982410241, 0.983035162, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.976666772, 1.019755049, 1.075189042, 0.975380543, 0.981316782, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.986876269, 1.026690916, 1.052379934, 1.001547298, 0.979888683, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.008209647, 0.976098272, 0.944479556, 0.996767684, 1.018077758, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.028862706, 1.08510417, 1.08963868, 1.048481179, 1.139954126, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.107066353, 1.122920581, 1.23904326, 1.19449336, 1.179971969, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.165865352, 1.068804094, 1.099436469, 1.073307737, 1.07045113, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.101007051, 1.011962649, 1.11202545, 1.097883672, 1.05361424, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.993283703, 1.046635444, 1.04951188, 0.086720869, 0.113119382, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.088197332, 0.081547788, 0.079373211, 0.07888827, 0.072865285, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.079637996, 0.066314774, 0.097585729, 0.185034982, 0.214466904, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.294317625, 0.481389256, 0.531196058, 0.715842439, 0.865098887, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.987242052, 1.081028291, 1.240920518, 1.313524957, 1.543771699, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.78495042, 1.746572555, 2.048760527, 2.101438775, 1.967474033, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                2.000286925, 2.014020838, 1.924470659, 1.75696549, 1.786681246, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.633290961, 1.455799758, 1.315346538, 1.435348984, 1.27887702, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.152818928, 1.095127218, 0.987502349, 1.062278922, 0.898540082, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.83617998, 0.889057689, 0.825563648, 0.788347646, 0.790973555, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.775541228, 0.815063004, 0.848723108, 0.66783059, 0.672629631, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.747809615, 0.72338158, 0.666220438, 0.664051795, 0.597260657, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.689282162, 0.663808452, 0.678551141, 0.672917354, 0.686199986, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.724202364, 0.746195474, 0.686135659, 0.654148537, 0.713488795, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.72446665, 0.699529989, 0.630120423, 0.661767463, 0.663290351, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.705879842, 0.709399338, 0.76228353, 0.714368918, 0.720561695, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.837036666, 0.923882149, 1.014163852, 1.221410703, 1.315825246, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.368054705, 1.641746627, 1.630198312, 1.698589629, 1.562956393, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.427322658, 1.53964983, 1.574583495, 1.527101216, 1.380123116, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.28649445, 1.29251968, 1.330565441, 1.317758525, 1.19292313, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.217953538, 1.218591815, 0.746612627, 0.818368055, 0.696689824, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.748702805, 0.717457681, 0.766243608, 0.805305259, 0.855909762, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.803357905, 0.889646097, 0.854456208, 1.067795473, 1.051422575, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.17061972, 1.138440648, 1.052796919, 1.040998633, 1.161739158, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.025956799, 0.971567748, 1.072911493, 0.952121155, 1.040392714, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.069745522, 1.068549198, 1.090194087, 1.214584829, 1.157485471, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.245813376, 1.336359991, 1.204038397, 1.126255292, 1.131057736, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.922042386, 1.037566449, 1.100852394, 1.121842367, 0.998657748, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.006938923, 1.002800377, 0.897387497, 0.93902937, 0.889327622, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.802133735, 0.855245047, 0.860702407, 0.704324249, 0.905827093, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.760155095, 0.760247698, 0.655991619, 0.677006743, 0.668001976, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.623410532, 0.569302474, 0.523713794, 0.690042836, 0.539115342, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.528696218, 0.57851915, 0.60294784, 0.581392042, 0.65277069, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.65620614, 0.625397246, 0.697647782, 0.6180657, 0.632326126, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.684659215, 0.606197513, 0.630134281, 0.637151517, 0.574538208, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.605993607, 0.533522181, 0.544522236, 0.577535469, 0.573427383, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.672984155, 0.735286828, 0.7532343, 0.881292245, 0.801132661, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.122761046, 1.137397845, 1.173190388, 1.138033979, 1.126494557, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.144871399, 1.087042815, 0.981750792, 0.992888445, 0.955352455, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.074357698, 1.027127808, 1.083248059, 1.010304962, 1.037776316, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.052809984, 0.742734852, 0.839492568, 0.743899849, 0.817080816, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.773569657, 0.735728339, 0.715168283, 0.78077814, 0.694280484, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.773303425, 0.768041196, 0.883401699, 0.818274274, 0.715927964, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.696938222, 0.832246446, 0.73089346, 0.790965216, 0.799717389, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.865896893, 0.946771069, 0.954212275, 1.023740345, 1.027036123, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                1.086336263, 1.064542815, 0.9463809, 0.924081609, 0.999832641, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.911277648, 0.922871168, 0.953134033, 0.786732115, 0.802026729, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.832863371, 0.863952475, 0.817833153, 0.748586924, 0.72095701, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.738213943, 0.672736744, 0.704947698, 0.531743532, 0.634123809, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.683548549, 0.733277161, 0.608993729, 0.752162246, 0.568705823, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.643172511, 0.597251486, 0.655514695, 0.583437677, 0.557676441, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.646713866, 0.527005047, 0.578023512, 0.576281064, 0.600923204, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.578475648, 0.551957027, 0.585007991, 0.623858699, 0.630936819, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.636198589, 0.565476603, 0.658861425, 0.577557604, 0.629178306, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.646092809, 0.566079299, 0.60953767, 0.680135261, 0.500802233, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.704656678, 0.61109605, 0.645344144, 0.667139888, 0.734969576, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.780062983, 0.783090234, 0.83005691, 0.905356723, 0.933746319, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.947613375, 0.923115827, 0.873482691, 0.746883952, 0.850273618, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.795256154, 0.800825928, 0.772630039, 0.749567395, 0.7823457, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.772609842, 0.736269985, 0.699705666, 0.716860238, 0.65909369
                                                                                                                                                                )), row.names = c(NA, -396L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `linetype` parameter with the aestethics :

```r
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Distance, y = value, color = variable, linetype = variable))
```

[image: line graph with linetype by variable]